# Set icon font as background in CSS property

Tags: html, css, wordpress, icons

All I want to do is replace a background image in CSS with an icon font, not icon image.
I can't get it done.
This is the CSS property:

```
.social-networks .twitter{background:url(../images/social/twitter.png);}
```

This is the code in PHP:

```
<ul class="social-networks">
    <?php if (my_option('twitter_link')): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo my_option('twitter_link'); ?>"  class="twitter">twitter</a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

The way I insert an incon font is `<span class="icon">A</span>`

Comment: I don't think this is possible, except (possibly) in Firefox: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WJVZ2/). (But I'm not wholly sure I understand your question, or requirements).

Comment: I just want to call a icon font as a background for a css property, is there any way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could try something like this: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Dim13i/9Hazh/)**

Let's say you have your DIV:

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

you create your css style like this:

```
.test {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid lightblue;
}

.test:before {
    content: "H";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 5.0em;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    line-height: 100px;
}​
```

in the property `content` you choose your "letter" and then you can change the `font-size`, `font-weight`, `color`, etc...

Comment: Note that this will not work for replaced content, such as inputs, because they cannot contain any children (except `<button>`)

Answer (score 5):

There is a content property in css:

```
.icon-rocket:after {
   content: "{Symbol for rocket}";
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp

Answer (score 0):

use navigation text instead of background img.

```
$(".slider").owlCarousel({
    navigation : true,
    slideSpeed : 500,
    singleItem:true,
    navigationText:['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>']
});
```

and set css property for font awesome icon.
here is normal css for icon.

```
.owl-button{
   position:relative;
}
.owl-prev {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:47%;
   font-size: 30px;
}
.owl-next {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:47%;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something interesting, imo: the CSS `element()` function. Currently it [works only in firefox](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20el) (so make sure you are opening example linked at the end in that browser).

Here is HTML:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
  rel="stylesheet">

<div class="bg-patterns">
  <i class="material-icons" id="icon">pets</i>
</div>

<div class="with-icon-bg">
   Hi! I'm paragraph with background made from ordinary HTML element! And BTW - I'm a pets lover. 
</div>
```

...and CSS with comments:

```
.material-icons {
  /* icon font */
  font-family: 'Material Icons'; 
  color: #ddd;
}

/* this is a wrapper for elements you want to use
as backgrounds, should not be visible on page */
.bg-patterns {
  margin-left: -90000cm; 
}

.with-icon-bg {
  /* all magic happens here */
  background: -moz-element(#icon);


  /* other irrelevant styling */
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 228px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 3px dashed #ddd;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And finally - there is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/mxo51qu9/2/) (jsFiddle).