# how do i add permanent place holder inside input filed

Tags: html, input, font-awesome

i need to add `font-icon` inside input field so i used this method

```
 <input type="text" name="your name" placeholder="&#xe00b; YOUR NAME" style="font-family:Flaticon" class="restrict">
```

as you see `placeholder="&#xe00b; YOUR NAME"` this `&#xe00b;` display `font-icon` but my problem is when user types some text place holder disapper so i need font icon to be placed permanent inside input field like `<lable>`

can someone help me

Comment: This cannot be accomplished with the `placeholder` property - you should rather set the icon as the text field's background and properly position that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869618/set-icon-font-as-background-in-css-property might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't.** What do you expect it to look like? `placeholder` disappears **by design**.

If you want **to prefix an icon in front of your input field**, put them together in a container, give this container the needed style and put there your icon and your `input`-tag. That's the way, [how bootstrap your problem solves](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#with-optional-icons).

[image: Example of bootstrap.]

Shortened example:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount">
</div>
```

Of course, you need CSS.

Comment: am using Bootstrap v3.1.1

Comment: This makes it easier. Just follow my link and you have your solution.

Comment: how do i increase input height

Comment: Please check the bootstrap documentation. If you need further assistance, feel free to open another question.