# How can I keep a placeholder character on a input field with Angular Material Design

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

[image: Money Placeholder - Material Design]

Looking at the above image you can add a dollar sign ($) by adding a placeholder attribute to a Material Design/Angular Directive. When you focus on the input and add text, the dollar sign disappears. Is there a way in CSS or otherwise were I can keep the dollar sign?

```
 <md-input-container >
    <label>Tens ($10.00's)</label>
    <input name="tens" ng-model="data.tens" placeholder="$">
  </md-input-container>
```

Comment: did you try just putting the dollar sign outside of the input? either that or make it a part of your `ng-model` but thats probably not the best idea.

Comment: That's the normal behaviour for a placeholder. Maybe you're looking for a mask.

Comment: I think this answer is explaining why you can't this and why you shouldn't :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817834/how-do-i-add-permanent-place-holder-inside-input-filed

Comment: @oguzhan00 good answer, but he doesn't have a bootstrap tag.

Comment: Thank you, you are right but as I know it is still impossible without some workaround with Js, html or css. Angular material doesn't have any tag or directive for this operation.

Comment: maybe you can use ng-keyup directive @Coded Container

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try **ng-change**, add **ng-change="change()"** to input

```
$scope.change = function () {
    if ($scope.data.tens === "$") {
        $scope.data.tens = "";
    }
    else if (!$scope.data.tens.startsWith('$')) {
      $scope.data.tens = '$' + $scope.data.tens;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are using your `ng-model` you can make the dollar sign a part of it - just make sure to not let the user delete the character.

```
<input name="tens" ng-model="data.tens">
```

Add a watcher to tens

```
    $scope.$watch('tens', function (newValue, oldValue) {
      if(newValue.length ==0){
         $scope.tens = $;
      }
});
```

Comment: I get an error that says, "cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: @CodedContainer that means newValue is probably null. Does tens start with a value? Instantiate it as an empty string

Comment: I don't want to start the value as an empty string because I want the user to know that the input should be added as a monetary value.

Comment: @CodedContainer sorry I meant that the instantiated value should be `"$"`

Comment: @CodedContainer no, the placeholder is separate from your `tens` value in the model.

Answer (score 0):

While many people have suggested using masks or Javascript, if what you're looking for is a *placeholder*-like option, I'll also add that you can use CSS to do the same.

CSS:

```
.dollar-sign-icon
{
    position: relative; /* adjust top and right to fit context */
}

.dollar-input
{
     padding-left: 30px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Tens ($10.00's)</label>
    <i class="dollar-sign-icon">$</i>
    <input class="dollar-input" name="tens" ng-model="data.tens" placeholder="$">
</md-input-container>
```